# Generar una fila por registro en un DataTable

Tags: jquery

Desarrollé un sistema de venta para cervecería donde, para cada tipo de medida de cerveza a la venta, hay una fila en una tabla donde se selecciona, ademas, el tipo de cerveza y luego tiene el botón agregar:

```
$.ajax({          
       type: "POST",
       url: "views/modules/medida/procesomedida.php",
       data:{"accion":"listar"},
       dataType:"json",

       error: function(){
          alert("error petición ajax");
       },
       success:function(data){
          listarp(data);
          $.each(data, function (index, item) {            

              contenido='<tr><td style="width:100px;"><input type="number" id="cant" min="1" name='+item.idmedida+' class="col-sm-12"  /></td> '+
              '<td style="width:200px;"><label id="'+item.capacidad+'" class="l" name="medida'+item.idmedida+'">'+item.descripcion+'</label></td>'+
              '<td style="width:400px;"><select id="'+item.idmedida+'" name="canillas'+item.idmedida+'" class="canillas" style="width:390px;"><option value="1">Seleccione</option></select></td>'+
              '<td><label name="'+item.idmedida+'"></label></td>'+          
              '<td><label  name="subtotal'+item.idmedida+'" id="sub" class="subtotal"></label></td>'+
              '<td style="width:100px;"><select id="'+item.idmedida+'" name="promo'+item.idmedida+'" class="promo"><option value=0>Seleccione</option></td>'+
              '<td><label name="total'+item.idmedida+'" class="total"></label></td>';             
              $(contenido).append('</tr><input type="button" value="Agregar" class="agrega" id="'+item.idmedida+'"/>');
              $(contenido).appendTo("#venta tbody");
          });
```

Como verán lo hice con un `each` recorriendo el `JSON`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero ahora quería hacerlo usando `DataTable` Plugin:

```
t = $('#factura').DataTable({    
         data:filtrado,              
         columns:[    { "data": "null", "title":"CANT.:"  ,"render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return '<input type="number" id="cant" min="1" name='+row.idmedida+' class="col-sm-6"  />';
    } },
     { "data": "null", "title":"MEDIDA","render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return '<label id="'+row.capacidad+'" class="l" name="medida'+row.idmedida+'">'+row.descripcion+'</label>';
    } },
     { "data": "null","title":"CANILLA","render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return '<select id="'+row.idmedida+'" name="canillas'+row.idmedida+'" class="canillas" style="width:390px;"><option value="1">Seleccione</option></select>';
    } },
     { "data": "null","title":"P/U", "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return '<label name="'+row.idmedida+'"></label>';
    } },
         { "data": "null","title":"SUBTOTAL", "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return '<label  name="subtotal'+row.idmedida+'" id="sub" class="subtotal"></label>';
    } },
     { "data": "null","title":"PROMO", "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return '<select id="'+row.idmedida+'" name="promo'+row.idmedida+'" class="promo"><option value=0>Seleccione</option>';
    } },
     { "data": "null","title":"TOTAL", "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return '<label name="total'+row.idmedida+'" class="total"></label>';
    } },
    { "data": "null", "title":"ACCION","render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return '<input type="button" value="Agregar" class="agrega" id="'+row.idmedida+'"/>';
    } } ], });
```

Ya armé las columnas como verán, pero como hago para generar dichas columnas, en una fila por cada registro de medida?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder crear filas con columnas de manera dinámica usando [`DataTables`](https://datatables.net/) debes de conocer el método [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) que te permitirá crear filas con información dentro de ella y dibujarla, te muestro un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var mi_tabla = $('#factura').DataTable({
       "language": {
         "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"
       },
       "bDestroy": true                               
   });    
      for (var item = 0; item < 10; item++) {
        mi_tabla.row.add( [
          1,
          "20X20",
          "GRANDE",
          2000,
          2000,
          "NINGUNA",
          2000
        ] ).draw( false );  
      }
      
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="factura">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>CANT</th>
      <th>MEDIDA</th>
      <th>CANILLA</th>
      <th>P/U</th>
      <th>SUBTOTAL</th>
      <th>PROMO</th>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Lo que necesitarás para generar un fila con las columnas es la parte del código en donde:

1. Instancias creando tu `DataTable` guardándolo en una variable para alterarla con los métodos nativos de la liberaría.
2. Creas dinámicamente tu table con información ya con todos tus datos obtenidos iterándolos y dibujándolos en cada vuelta de tu iteración.

Yo lo simulo haciendo un `for` del 0 al 10 pero en tu caso tendrás que traer la información de tu base de datos con alguna petición `ajax` o como creas más conveniente. Al final, solo debes de hacer uso del método `draw` del cual ya te dejé referencia.